# Get encoded barcode as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am creating a web application (ASP.NET C#) where I need the encoded barcode text.

Example: EAN13 numbers: 460650003296. The output encoded barcode is then: Y(6A65AA*KNMTQT(
And that is the value I will need to have.

I have tried to use BarCodeLib and that it´s working great to generate barcodes images but I can´t find any way to get the encoded text, I have also tried KA Barcode but with the same result.

Does anyone have any experience in this libaries and if it´s possible to get the encoded text from them, or some other suggestion how I can get the encoded value?

Comment: http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/barcodes-in-c-sharp-interleaved-2-of-5/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Y(6A65AA*KNMTQT( has nothing to do with barcodes or the EAN standard. Where did you find this code?

Comment: I am using a font from IDautomation and when I am using the online encoder (http://www.bcgen.com/fontencoder/default.aspx) I get the encoded text ("Y(6A65AA*KNMTQT(").

Comment: They provided libraries to do this for you: http://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/

Comment: This text is only created so, when applied with IDAutomation font, it shows as barcode, llike Timo said, it has nothing to do with any barcode specification whatsoever. If you want to use IDAutomation font, you have to use [IDAutomation DLL](http://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/dotnet-assembly/)

Comment: I realized that now, thank you soo much for your help! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this library that you are using. However, my company created a web application that use different commercial library for reading and writing 1-D barcodes (including the EAN13).

We started our web application using the following 2 tutorials:

[Reading Barcodes](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/to/leadtools.topics.barcode~ba.topics.readingbarcodes.html)

[Writing Barcodes](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/to/leadtools.topics.barcode~ba.topics.writingbarcodes.html)

You can get more details from their support team using this email:

support@leadtools.com